# Is there any one-to-many notion of convolution?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, convolution

I'm looking for the properties of integrals in the following form:

$$G(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)=\int f(t) g(t-x_1, t-x_2, \ldots, t-x_n) dt $$

For $n=1$ the above integral is simply the convolution of $f$ and $g$, i.e. $G(x_1) = f * g$. Thus, I think the above integral should be some sort of generalized convolution.

> Is there any reference that studies these type of integrals?
>
> Is it possible to express the above integral as an ordinary convolution of two functions (perhaps using some auxiliary variables)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the answer! The given integral can be expressed in terms of an $n$-dimensional convolution.

We may write
$$G(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)=\int f(t) g(t-x_1, t-x_2, \ldots, t-x_n) dt \\
=\iiiint f(t)\delta(t-t_2)\delta(t-t_3)\ldots\delta(t-t_n) g(t-x_1, t_2-x_2, \ldots, t_n-x_n) dtdt_2dt_3\ldots dt_n$$
Where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta function. Hence, we may write:

$$G(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \hat{f}(x_1,\ldots, x_n) * g(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$$
Where $\hat{f}(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = f(x_1)\delta(x_1-x_2)\delta(x_1-x_3)\ldots\delta(x_1-x_n)$.